# Animated Title (Like Terraria's Game Title)

Tags: c#, .net, xna, title

What i want to do is make a title like Terraria just the rocking back and forth side of it not the graphics side i know that its just a .png rocking back and forth but could anyone help me and other people who read this and what to know how to do it?

So what i would like is to learn how to make a rocking back and forth image like the title displayed in Terraria?

Something like this for the people who don't know what Terraria is.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3K8PMG42l3M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the logo is rotating and changing its size over non-equal intervals of time.

First, you need to get familiar with [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff433988%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx):

> SpriteBatch.Draw Method (Texture2D, Vector2, Nullable, Color, Single, Vector2, Single, SpriteEffects, Single)

The parameters are:

```
Texture2D texture,                   // texture of your logo
Vector2 position,                    // where to draw
Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle, // null
Color color,                         // Color.White
float rotation,                      // you will be changing this
Vector2 origin,                      // and this
float scale,                         // also this
SpriteEffects effects,               // SpriteEffects.None
float layerDepth                     // 0
```

Use these variables:

```
float rotation = 0,
    rotationSpeed = 0.002f, // this is how much rotation will change each frame
    maximumAngle = 0.1f,
    minimumAngle = -0.1f,
    rotationDirection = 1,
    scale = 1f, // 1 means 100%, 0.95f = 95%
    scaleChange = 0.005f, // this may seem not much, but it's enough
    maxScale = 1.1f,
    minScale = 0.9f,
    scaleDirection = 1;
```

Just put `DrawLogo();` in your main `Draw()` method.

```
void DrawLogo()
{
    // these two very similar pieces of code will control scale and rotation

    if (rotationDirection > 0)
    {
        if (rotation < maximumAngle)
            rotation += rotationSpeed;
        else
            rotationDirection = -rotationDirection;
    }
    else
        if (rotation > minimumAngle)
            rotation -= rotationSpeed;
        else
            rotationDirection = -rotationDirection;

    if (scaleDirection > 0)
    {
        if (scale < maxScale)
            scale += scaleChange;
        else
            scaleDirection = -scaleDirection;
    }
    else
        if (scale > minScale)
            scale -= scaleChange;
        else
            scaleDirection = -scaleDirection;


    Texture2d t2d = logoTexture;

    spriteBatch.Draw(t2d,
        centerScreen,            // change this to `new Vector2(123, 456)`
        null,                    // null means draw entire texture
        Color.White,             // no tinting
        rotation,                // the rotation we calculate above
        new Vector2(t2d.Width / 2, t2d.Height / 2),
          // this sets rotation point to the center of the texture

        scale,                   // the scale we calculate above
        SpriteEffects.None,      // you can mirror your texture with this
        0);                      // I usually leave it zero :p
}
```

This is tested and works just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

You mean the effect we can see at about 1:16 (and probably also at other times), when you choose stuff in the menus?

### Concept

As far as I can see, you can do this with simple rotations and scaling. So, if you do not want to make an animated gif (which you suppose it is), you can just do it inside your XNA code. Take a png or gif with alpha-channel (so that the non-text is transparent).

Then, when you draw it on the screen with `spriteBatch.draw()` you can choose one of the overloads that [support **scaling** and **rotation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx).

Then you have to set:

- the rotation you want to have (which will be a rotation over time)
- the origin (to the center of the image)
- the scale (which will be scaling over time)

As the clock is sent to the `update()` method as far as I remember XNA, we will have to update the rotation and scale of the image there. We need the clock, because we cannot just set `rotaton = 10°` and XNA will handle everything for us. We have to calculate the current rotation in **each time step** ourselves. E.g. if a full rotation shall endure 10 seconds and 5 seconds have passed, then you know you have a half rotation. So we would tell XNA: `Set our rotation to 180° now`, and in the next time step, we might tell: `Set our rotation to 190° now`.

The basic concept is:

1. Calculate how much part of rotation/scale we have done in the current time step
2. Tell XNA to adjust this rotation/scale in this time step

   - Iterate these two steps again and again

### Implementation

I think the best thing to do here, is using a sin() or cos() function for the scaling and rotation. The good things about them:

- they have positive and negative values as well (so we can easily rotate in both directions)
- they are smooth, meaning your rotation and scaling will not look too abrupt at the end of the rotation/scaling

I hope my maths is correct here. I will explain everything, so others can correct me if something is wrong. Or also you can find out, if something is wrong. We will use a sin() here, because it starts at 0, which in our case means that nothing should happen. That’s what we want: We want to begin at a situation where nothing happens.

Now, sin() has a cycle time of 2*PI. Of course, we do not want a scaling to last 2*PI, but rather something like 1000 milliseconds. We cannot change the definition of `Math.Sin()` in C#, but we can change the value we throw inside. So when we mean 1000 milliseconds, we will give `Math.Sin()` 2PI and when we mean 500 milliseconds, we give it PI.

We would define these member variables:

```
// define some variables for rotation and scale speed, in milliseconds 
int fullRotationTime = 1000; // max rotation will be reached after 1 second
float maxRotationAngle = MathHelper.ToRadians(10); // we will rotate by 10 degree up and down
int rotationTimePassed = 0;
float currentRotationAngle = 0;

int fullScaleTime = 1000; // max scale will be reached after 1 second
float maxScaleSize = 1.2f; // we will scale to 20% larger max
int scaleTimePassed = 0;
float currentScaleFactor = 1.0;
```

And in the `Update()` method, we calculate how much of our rotation we already have done.

```
protected virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    int milliseconds = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

    // these are the milliseconds in the current rotation
    rotationTimePassed += milliseconds;
    scaleTimePassed += milliseconds;

    if (rotationTimePassed >= fullRotationTime)
        rotationTimePassed %= fullRotationTime;
    if (scaleTimePassed >= fullScaleTime)
        scaleTimePassed %= fullScaleTime;


    float rotationTimeAdjustedToTwoPi = ((float)rotationTimePassed)/fullRotationTime * 2* Math.PI);
    currentRotationAngle = maxRotationAngle * Math.Sin(rotationTimeAdjustedToTwoPi);

    // we do not want the scaling to be negative, thus we add 1 to the whole and
    // divide by 2. Then the maximum will be 1 and the minimum 0
    float scaleTimeAdjustedToTwoPi = ((float)scaleTimePassed)/fullScaleTime * 2* Math.PI);
    currentScaleFactor = maxScaleSize * (Math.Sin(scaleTimeAdjustedToTwoPi) + 1)/2;
}
```

Then, in the `Draw()` method we can take the values calculated before and display our rotated and scaled image.

```
protected virtual void Draw()
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture,
        new Vector2(50, 50),
        null,
        Color.White,
        currentRotationAngle,
        new Vector2(texture.width/2, texture.height/2),
        currentScaleFactor,
        SpriteEffects.None,
        0
    );
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

It’s not tested, so there might even be syntax errors, but I at least the basic idea should be correct and I think the important thing is that you understand **how** it can be done conceptually.

### Variable time steps

It’s easy to integrate the variable time steps *user1306322* has mentioned into the code above. We had these if-conditions where we checked if the current time-slice is over, like this: `if (rotationTimePassed >= fullRotationTime)`.

Now it we want to make the time-slices variable length, just adjust a new time-slice based on a random number here. Like this:

```
var rand = new Random();

if (rotationTimePassed >= fullRotationTime)
{
    rotationTimePassed %= fullRotationTime;

    // next rotation might take between 0.5 and 2.5 seconds
    fullRotationTime = rand.next(500, 2500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it out now just one question how do i integrate XNA into Microsoft Visual Studio? or is there another application that i can use that contains XNA Code?

Comment: @Terrii install it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714

Comment: but how do i integrate it into my code do i add a "Using System.XNA" or something?

Comment: @Terrii after installing XNA game studio, Visual Studio will have three new project types: PC game, Xbox 360 game and Windows Phone game. You need to create a new project (I assume it's a PC game), and add your existing code there. If this is your first time working with an XNA project, there is a great tutorial from Microsoft: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started You should also look for XNA beginner tutorial questions on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [GameDev.SE].